# Do your Clash of Clans Mortars Hurt your own queen or king?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Do any defensive weapons like cannon or mortar hurt a persons own king or queen? Another player thinks people lure her queen and king out to be slaughtered by own weapons. I doubt it but am I right?

Answer (score 7):

Quote from the "[Defensive Buildings](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Defensive_Buildings)" page on the wiki:

> Defenses serve to safeguard trophies and protect resources from **enemy** troops.

Quote from the "[Mortar](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Mortar)" page on the wiki:

> Their splash damage, combined with their long range, make them deadly weapons against large numbers of weaker **enemies** such as Barbarians, Archers or Goblins. Its major disadvantages are its inability to attack **enemies** at close range and its low rate of fire.

Notice the use of the word "enemy" and "enemies" in these quotes.

There is no evidence of own troops taking damage from defensive buildings. This is also backed up by the fact that your own towers only target enemy troops.

As for "luring", this is a strategy where drop a few troops in the corner of an enemy base, luring the Heroes and enemy Clan Castle troops into the corner, then drop lightning spells on them to kill them.

[As of version 6.186.1](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Version_History#Version_6.186.1_-_3rd_July_2014_.22Hero_Changes.22), the "luring" strategy has been nerfed, this is explained on the "[Version History](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Version_History#Version_6.186.1_-_3rd_July_2014_.22Hero_Changes.22)" page:

> The heroes have gotten sick and tired of being lured out and squashed in the edges of the map. Now, they only attack targets in a limited territory around their platform and will retreat if they get drawn away too far.

To answer you question, your own troops cannot be damaged by your own towers. Once Heroes were lured out, they were damaged by lightning spells, not your own mortars. Your mortars would have targeted the troops used to lure the heroes, but will not damage your troops.

Answer (score 2):

You own King/Queen cannot be hurt buy you own weapons. They lure them out in order to ambush them so they don't need to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

No, defensive buildings cannot hit your heroes or clan castle troops. Luring the heroes out is to kill them without defensive buildings attacking their troops